# Why are the sharps of sets of big ordinals not in $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory, inner-models

In his talk [A Condensed History of Condensation](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emapdw/EUSetTheory.pdf), Welch presents the following recursive sharp function, that is total when all sharps exist:

\begin{align*}
\# \colon ON &\to \mathcal{P}(ON) \\
\alpha &\mapsto (\#\restriction \alpha)^\#
\end{align*}

My question is, why does the co-domain need to be $\mathcal{P}(ON)$, and isn't restricted just to $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$?

I get that maybe for bigger sets $A$ the class of indiscernibles of $L[A]$ will vary, but after all its sharp will always be a set of sentences of the theory of $L[A]$. And isn't this theory always countable (and thus a member of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ by Gödel Numbering)? Isn't the only additional symbol of the language of that theory one predicate symbol interpreted as $A$, no matter how big the members of $A$?

I can also frame my question in a more straight forward way. Consider instead the function:
\begin{align*}
F \colon \mathcal{P}(ON) &\to \mathcal{P}(ON) \\
x &\mapsto x^\#
\end{align*}

Assuming all sharps exist, so that $F$ is total, how com some $x^\#$ are not members of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$?

Comment: I think the point is that for $L[A]$, $A$ a set of ordinals, the $#$ of $A$ is a collection of sentences in the language of set theory, with constants $c_\delta$ added, for $\delta < \sup(A)$. Hence it becomes a subset of $sup(A)$.

Comment: @PhilipWelch Thank you very much for your comment, Philip! Yes, thanks to discussion with Bagaria (my supervisor) I realized exactly what you mention.
In case it is of any interest to you, here's my [Thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10754), from which the question arised. In it (Chapter 3), I relate your results on Acceptability to some basic tools for the study of Gaps in Inner Models.